# Why isn't #include working on .asp page in IIS7.5?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, server-side-includes

I saw a similar question to this, but mine is slightly different:

I'm get intermittent results with #include files working on an IIS 7.5 server (R2008 V2). My includes are only working if they are in the same folder as the current .asp page, or in a subfolder of the current page. This is inconvenient, as I'd like to keep them all in a /lib subfolder, off of the main page.

My configuration: I have a folder named DCN, sitting right below the wwwroot folder. There are several files in a /lib folder within the DCN folder, so the absolute path is c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dcn\lib\my_include_file.asp. If I open an ASP page in the DCN folder, I can pull include files from the /lib subfolder. However, if I open an ASP page from the DCN/trouble folder (such as "DCN\Trouble\Search.asp"), and the search.asp page has a line that says:

```
<!--#include file="../lib/my_include_file.asp"-->
```

the include fails, and I get a 500 error.

I've also tried:

```
<!--#include file="/lib/my_include_file.asp"-->
```

with the same results. Same with:

```
<!--#include file="/DCN/lib/my_include_file.asp"-->
```

I changed the slashes to backslashes, with the same results. I even went so far as to try:

```
 <!--#include file="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dcn\lib\my_include_file.asp"-->
```

(out of sheer desparation), but am still getting the same results.

If I create a subfolder in the dcn\trouble folder, I can include files from it, but obviously, this is not ideal.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I can't help but think this is something trivial. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you cheched the ACL in the lib folder?

Answer (score 7):

Yots is correct, it sounds like parent paths are turned off. If you can't get these turned on the use virtual paths instead:

Based on your question where you state that the include files are in `/DCN/lib` then do the following:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/DCN/lib/my_include_file.asp -->
```

When using virtual paths you must specify the full virtual path to the file i.e. from the root of the site. This isn't ideal if you're building your application in a subfolder on your development machine where you're using XP and then deploying into the root of a production machine. That said IIS7 on Vista or Windows 7 permits the creation of multiple sites now **.

When using a path type of `File="..."`, *filename* must be on a relative path to the folder containing the #include. For example:

The directive `<!-- #include file="my_include.asp" -->` will include `my_include.asp` from the same folder.

The directive `<!-- #include file="lib/my_include.asp" -->` will include `my_include.asp` from the folder `lib` below the current folder where the script is running.

The directive `<!-- #include file="../my_include.asp" -->` will include `my_include.asp` from the folder `lib` above the current folder (the parent folder) where the script is running.

The directive `<!-- #include file="../lib/my_include.asp" -->` will include `my_include.asp` from the folder `lib` that is a child of the parent folder (or the current folder's sibling).

The last two examples won't work if parent paths are not enabled.

** *I am aware there are hacks to enable multiple IIS sites in XP's IIS5.1.*

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that parent paths are disabled by default in IIS.

You have two options:

1. Using Virtual Paths
2. Enabling ASP Parent Paths on IIS

For details read this article from the IIS Website
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/566/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default/

Comment: `<!--#include file="/lib/my_include_file.asp"-->` should work even when Parent Paths are disabled

Comment: @eduardo - it won't, he'd need to use `<!-- #include virtual="..." -->` instead. `<!--#include file="..." -->` only supports relative paths.

Comment: That was it exactly.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 4):

What about a `#include virtual`?  if it reads:

```
#include virtual="\mysite\include\file.inc
```

it should find the `file.inc` in the include folder under mysite?  I have enabled and disabled parent paths and tried about a million things.  I still receive an `asp 0126 error` for the file not found.  I can swtich it to include file and then it finds it, but then the file.inc has a bunch of other includes and it then cant find them no matter how i change it to include file or virtual.  It works in IIS 6, but not IIS 7 that i am moving this site to.  It is a classic asp page with mostly everything done in include files

I have mysite in the `Default Web site\dept_Sites\mysite` location.